# Enormous confusion with MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio

Tags: mono

I'm extremely confused at the moment and I would appreciate answers.

I want to develop desktop applications for Linux, Mac and Windows using C#. My understanding was that Mono supports many languages and is Open-Source and hence; free. When I went to download MonoDevelop (which I gather is the Mono IDE) I was instead corralled into downloading Xamarin Studio, which I understand to be a re-branded MonoDevelop 4.0. The MonoDevelop website claims that MonoDevelop can handle all kinds of applications (C#, C, C++, F#, Java, etc.) but when I download and open Xamarin Studio I'm met with something very different. From what I'm gathering, Xamarin Studio is for developing iOS and Android apps.

I'd really appreciate knowing what on earth is going on. There seem to be 4 or 5 types of Xamarin IDE, and people still refer to it as MonoDevelop. It's extremely confusing and I'm totally lost.

Any help and guidance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MonoDevelop is completely opensource and you can find its source code here: http://github.com/mono/monodevelop . You can install MonoDevelop from most Linux distributions out there, it's free.

Now, if you're not using Linux, it turns out nobody in the Mono community has stepped up to provide binaries for nonLinux platforms, therefore, unless you want to spend time on this, what you have to do to run MonoDevelop in Windows or Mac is to simply use XamarinStudio, which is essentially MonoDevelop, but it has 2 or 3 addins which are not opensource. So, the "core" of XamarinStudio is still MonoDevelop and is still opensource. Any thing you can do with MonoDevelop, you can do it with Xamarin Studio.

But Xamarin Studio also includes Xamarin branding (which MonoDevelop doesn't have), and Mobile/Mac-development add-ins. If you don't want to use them, it's fine, don't use them. Just use XamarinStudio in the same way you would be using MonoDevelop, without using Xamarin's features.

**UPDATE 2018**: Microsoft has discontinued the XamarinStudio brand, and the equivalent product is now called `Visual Studio for Mac` (also based in MonoDevelop core).

Comment: That actually clears a lot of it up - thankyou for taking the time. I'll have more of a play with Xamarin now that I know that's where I should actually be looking. I'm very grateful for the clarification @knocte, thankyou again.